# Google Sheet script getValues and when find the given value, replace the value of the above row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I modify the script below to read the values in a column, but only read the values of the specified cells: L9, L10 ... L18, L19 .... L27, L28 .... (two by two jumping eight, to the end of the column L2000) and when find the value "1" in one of those cells, then replace the value that is 4 lines up with "FALSE"?

e.g. if cell L19 is found the number 1, then replace the value of cell L15 with the word "FALSE" ... and if cell L28 is found the number 1, then replace the value of cell L24 with the word "FALSE"

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ABC"); 
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow(); 
var range = ss.getRange(9, 12, lastrow - 1, 1); 
var data = range.getValues(); 
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { 
  if (data[i][0] == "1") { 
    data[i][0] = "FALSE"; 
  } 
} 
range.setValues(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another counter to loop: Try Modifying

From:

```
var range = ss.getRange(9, 12, lastrow - 1, 1); 
var data = range.getValues(); 
   for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { 
     if (data[i][0] == "1") { 
      data[i][0] = "FALSE"; 
    } 
   }
```

To:

```
var range = ss.getRange(5, 12, lastrow+5, 1); 
var data = range.getValues(); 
var m= 0;
for (var i=4; i < data.length; ) { 
  if (data[i][0] == "1") {
    data[i-4][0] = "FALSE";
  }
  m++;
  if (m == 2) {
    m=0; 
    i = i + 8;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: works partially / did not work.
This script only finds the first value "1" in the column, but that found value is in a cell that should not be considered.
I need to figure out how to delimit the getValues only for cells L9, L10 ... L18, L19 .... L27, L28 .... (two by two jumping eight, to the end of the column L2000) and then, when found the value "1" in one of these specific cells, replace by FALSE the value that is 4 rows above.
I added an link/example to the question.

Comment: Now worked perfectly!
Thank you so much, you've helped me a lot!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My take on what the loop should become:

```
var range = ss.getRange(9, 12, lastrow - 1, 1);
var data = range.getValues();
var i = 4,
    // Subtract 1 here because we compare both i and i+1 in the same loop body
    len = data.length - 1;
while (i < len) {
  // Check the value of the first row in the subset.
  if (data[i][0] == 1) {
    data[i - 4][0] = "FALSE";
  }
  // Check the next row in the subset.
  if (data[++i][0] == 1) {
    data[i - 4][0] = "FALSE";
  }
  // Advance to the next subset.
  i += 8;
}
```

Comment: It did not work, nothing happens when I run this script. I did not check what might be missing to work.
Even so, really thank you for your attention!
Doubt solved.